# Filling struct array in golang

Tags: go

I have struct like

```
type Coverage struct {
  neoCoverage        []NeoCoverage
  ApocCoverage       []ApocCoverage
  ApocConfigCoverage []ApocConfigCoverage
}
```

**And**

```
type NeoCoverage struct {
  Name   string
  Number string
}
```

So how should i fill coverage struct?

Here how I am Trying.

```
coverage = Coverage{
 []neoCoverage: NeoCoverage{
     Name:   "xyz",
     Number: "xyz123",
   },
 }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Something like below

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    type NeoCoverage struct {
        Name   string
        Number string
    }

    type Coverage struct {
        neoCoverage []NeoCoverage
    }

    coverage := Coverage {
        neoCoverage: []NeoCoverage {
            NeoCoverage{ Name: "xyz", Number: "xyz123" },
            NeoCoverage{ Name: "abc", Number: "abc123" },
        },
    }

    fmt.Println(coverage)
}
```

Output

```
{[{xyz xyz123} {abc abc123}]}
```

Here is the brief explanation; `neoCoverage: []NeoCoverage{}` stands for the slice of `NeoCoverage` and that slice should be populated with `NeoCoverage{}` elements as in `NeoCoverage{ Name: "xyz", Number: "xyz123" }, ...`

Answer (score 10):

You can also omit the redundant Type declarations in the array. Using Alper's code base as example.

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    type NeoCoverage struct {
         Name   string
         Number string
    }

    type Coverage struct {
        neoCoverage []NeoCoverage
    }

    coverage := Coverage {
        neoCoverage: []NeoCoverage {
            { Name: "xyz", Number: "xyz123" },
            { Name: "abc", Number: "abc123" },
        },
    }

    fmt.Println(coverage)
}
```

Output:

```
{[{xyz xyz123} {abc abc123}]}
```